# random point in a convex polyhedral region

Tags: random

How does one effectively generate a uniformly distributed random point in some bounded convex polyhedral region R in a Euclidean space? If codimension is zero I could surround the region with a rectangular region and generate point in the rectangular region rejecting it, if it is not in R.
This is not very efficient and does not work, if codimension is positive.

Typical example would be: generate uniformly distributed random (p_1,...,p_n) in a simplex, that is p_i>=0, for all i and p_1+...+p_n=1.

Comment: For those of us unfamiliar with the notion of codimensionality (me!), why does rejection sampling fail in some circumstances?

Comment: A subspace in n-dimensional space has codimension k if its dimension is n-k. Rejection sampling fails because the probability you'll accept a sample is 0; try rejection sampling a line in 3-space.

Comment: Can one simplify your question to "how do I create a random point inside a polygon", or does this indeed need terminology such as "bounded convex polyhedral region R in a Euclidean space"? (Because I *have* an answer for the simplified version :-))

Comment: @Jongware: By polygon do you mean a region in the plane? My problem is when the number of variables is greater then the number of degrees of freedom, as in the example above: n variables satifying 1 relation. so the real dimension of the region is n-1. Explain your solution anyway.

Comment: Umm, by "polygon" I mean a simple polygon .. (If that is "a region in the plane", then so be it.) You can triangulate a polygon, sum up the areas of all triangles, and then pick a random point "in" the total area. Then find the *triangle* that corresponds with that point and generate a random point inside it. That's merely a 2D solution, not for subspace or hyperspace, though. (Somehow I got the feeling this is not actually about my area of expertise.)

Comment: @Jongware: will be hard to generalize for dimension bigger then 2. Thanks anyway. Good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a subspace of codimension k, that means your convex polytope is defined by some number of inequalities and k independent equalities. So you can still use modified rejection sampling:

1. Find n-k independent variables p_1 through p_{n-k}.
2. Compute the possible ranges for those variables
3. Sample each variable.
4. Compute p_{n-k+1} through p_n
5. Accept if it's within your simplex, else reject and repeat.

I'm fairly sure this is still uniform because the dependent variables are related linearly to the independent ones and so mumble Jacobian mumble linearity, but I can't quite prove it.

Comment: Yes, that works. Uniformity only depends on the linear structure, of course, since, as you said, Jacobian of a linear map is constant and will be killed off by scaling to make measure probabilistic.